# How to Separate Letters and Symbols from String.(Almost Done)

Tags: java, string, javac, symbols, letters

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Separate {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in ); 
    String variable;
    System.out.print("Enter Variable:");
      variable = user_input.next();
          Separate(variable);
   }

   public static void Separate(String str) {
          String number = "";
          String letter = "";
      String symbol = "";
          for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                 char a = str.charAt(i);
                 if (Character.isDigit(a)) {
                       number = number + a;

                 } else {
                       letter = letter + a;


         }
          }
          System.out.println("Alphabets in string:"+letter);
          System.out.println("Numbers in String:"+number);   
   }
```

}

Okay, i already have this code which separate the Numbers and Letters that i Input. The problem is, when ever i input Symbols for example (^,+,-,%,*) it also states as a Letter.

What i want to do is to separate the symbol from letters just like what i did on Numbers and Letters and make another output for it.

Comment: You can use a regex based solution I think

Comment: Have you tried with Regular Experssion? That should work for your problem. Give a look at [Regular Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing if the character `isDigit`, `else` treat it as a letter. 
Well, if it is not a digit, all other cases go to `else`, in your code. Create an `else` case for those symbols also.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void separate(String string) {
        StringBuilder alphabetsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder numbersBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder symbolsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            char ch = string.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isAlphabetic(ch)) {
                alphabetsBuilder.append(ch);
            } else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                numbersBuilder.append(ch);
            } else {
                symbolsBuilder.append(ch);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Alphabets in string: " + alphabetsBuilder.toString());
        System.out.println("Numbers in String: " + numbersBuilder.toString());
        System.out.println("Sysmbols in String: " + symbolsBuilder.toString()); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As this reeks of homework, just see the [documentation of Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html), which had that nice function `isDigit`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Separate(String str) 
{
    String number = "";
    String letter = "";
    String symbol = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
    {
        char a = str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(a)) 
        {
            number = number + a;
            continue;
        } 
        if(Character.isLetter(a))
        {
            letter = letter + a;
        }
        else
        {
            symbol = symbol + a;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Alphabets in string:"+letter);
    System.out.println("Numbers in String:"+number);   
}
```

Comment: Preferably use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Thankyou! This Works! Cheers! The truth is i didnt know that you can use keywords such as continue;  Anw Thankyou again!

Comment: @Mr.Yoso - you can do the same thing without using `continue`. Just have an else if & then an else.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Separate {

public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );

      String variable;

      System.out.print("Enter Variable:");

      variable = user_input.next();

      Separate(variable);
   }

         public static void Separate(String str) 
         {
          String number = "";

          String letter = "";

          String symbol = "";

          for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

                 char a = str.charAt(i);

                 if (Character.isDigit(a)) {
                       number = number + a;

                 } else if (Character.isLetter(a)) {
                       letter = letter + a;
                 } else {
                       symbol = symbol + a;
         }
       }
     System.out.println("Alphabets in string:"+letter);
     System.out.println("Numbers in String:"+number);
     System.out.println("Symbols in String:"+symbol);   
   }

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!